# Displaying post with certain key value

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress function that displays all posts of a custom meta.

**PHP**:

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'todo_listing',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'order' => 'asc'
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);
while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    echo get_the_ID();
endwhile;
?>
```

This displays 4 posts per page. However, I only want to display those posts whose `$key` value is `dogs`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'todo_listing',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'order' => 'asc',
    'meta_value' => 'dogs'
);
```

Comment: This doesnt work as the key value is dogs and key is the post id

Comment: Sorry, I thought dogs was the key. I've updated my answer so the query should look for dogs in the meta value.

Comment: Maybe looking at http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters will help you. I'm pretty much out of ideas.